# How many chart positions are available in the Apple Music API?

Tags: apple-music, apple-musickit

Example call: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/charts?types=songs&genre=34

The help page (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_catalog_charts) says the results are paginated and can retrieve 50 positions at a time. I'm wondering how many positions total can be retrieved (or equivalently, what is the maximum offset)? Thanks.